# How to find out which parameter out of two was passed in python?

Tags: python

Suppose we want to add support for a new parameter name in a function, without removing the old one (rather adding deprecation warning for that)

```
def f(a=2, b=2):
    # we want users to use b, so need to pass deprecation 
    # warning for a when a is used.
    if(b is 2 and a is not 2): # a is used
        warnings.warn("a is deprecated in future update. Please use b")
        # But we miss case when a=2 is passed
```

Please suggest what could be a better way to have this feature. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `None` as the default value for `a`. If `None` is a valid value that a user might pass in, use some unique object that only you have access to:

```
missing = object()

def f(a=missing, b=2):
    if a is not missing:
        # etc.
```

In general, this code has a smell... there is probably a better way to design your API so that you don't have this problem in the first place.

Comment: Presumably, the default values are suited to the specific case. For example, let's imagine that `print` was originally for CSVs and had a `delimiter=','` default argument, and only later was `sep=' '` added, and you want to give a warning for when someone uses `delimiter`.

Comment: Deprecating an argument is pretty unusual, in my experience, that's all.

Comment: I like the idea of using some unique object. The API is in development phase so need a deprecation warning for time being. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Make `a = None`.

```
def f(a=None, b=None):
    if a is not None:
        warnings.warn("a is deprecated in future update. Please use b")
```

By the way, python2 has a built-in [DeprecationWarning](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.DeprecationWarning) and a [PendingDeprecationWarning](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.PendingDeprecationWarning). Check them out.

```
def f(a=None, b=None):
    if a is not None:
        raise PendingDeprecationWarning('a is deprecated in future update. Please use b')
```

Worth noticing that PendingDeprecationWarning won't stop the execution like a normal exception would do. This is the result of raising that exception:

```
PendingDeprecationWarning('a is deprecated in future update. Please use b',)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a `kwargs` to the function like this:

```
def f(**kwargs):
    a = kwargs.get('a', 2)
    if 'a' in kwargs:
        print('Deprecation warning')
    b = kwargs.get('b', 2)
```

or even:

```
def f(b=2, **kwargs):
    a = kwargs.get('a', 2)
    if 'a' in kwargs:
        print('Deprecation warning')
```

Comment: I don't think it goes without saying that you should explicitly check `not set(kwargs) - set('ab')`, since this is supposed to mimic a function with exactly two arguments.

Comment: Issue with first one is that it can't be used with positional arguments anymore, secondly its function signature is lost.